# Move Sprite Based Off of Degrees

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift4

I've been able to detect degrees, but I'm unsure on how to move the sprite in 360 degrees.
[image: drawing]
I don't want the sprite to be able to only move in certain sections, as shown in the picture above, but rather have it be able to move in a full circle.
Code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if (ball.frame.contains(location)) {

            stickActive = true
        }else {

            stickActive = false

        }

    }

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if (stickActive == true) {


            var v = CGVector(dx: location.x - base.position.x, dy: location.y - base.position.y)
            let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
            var deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
            print(deg + 180)

            let lenght:CGFloat = base.frame.size.height / 2 - 20
            let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * lenght
            let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * lenght
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: base.position.x - xDist, y: base.position.y + yDist)

            if (base.frame.contains(location)) {

                ball.position = location
            }else {

                ball.position = CGPoint(x: base.position.x - xDist, y: base.position.y + yDist)

            }

        }

    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (stickActive == true) {


        let move: SKAction = SKAction.move(to: base.position, duration: 0.2)
        move.timingMode = .easeOut

        ball.run(move)


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a joystick? if you are I can help you set this up, its quite simple.

Comment: Sorry if my question was a little confusing, but I would like to make a joystick.

Comment: My answer will provide everything you need to set up a joystick, assuming your using spritekit?

Comment: I'm testing it out now. Thanks

Comment: any issues? did I answer your question? If so, you need to mark my answer as correct so that future viewers don't get confused.

Comment: Works great! Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help! :) this took me forever to figure out, and Im glad I could help someone else with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super simple, although it took me quite awhile to figure out how to do it.

TouchesBegan method:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if isTracking == false && DPad.contains(location) {
            isTracking = true
        }
    }
}
```

TouchesMoved method:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        if isTracking == true {

            v = CGVector(dx: location.x - DPad.position.x, dy: location.y - DPad.position.y)
            let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
            let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / Double.pi)

            let Length:CGFloat = DPad.frame.size.height / 2
            let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * Length
            let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * Length

            xJoystickDelta = location.x - DPad.position.x
            yJoystickDelta = location.y - DPad.position.y

            if DPad.contains(location) {
                thumbNode.position = location
            } else {
                thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x - xDist, y: DPad.position.y + yDist)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TouchesEnded method:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTracking = false
    thumbNode.run(SKAction.move(to: DPad.position, duration: 0.01))
    xJoystickDelta = 0
    yJoystickDelta = 0
}
```

The `update(_ currentTime:)` method:

```
    if v.dx > abs(v.dy) {
        yourPlayer.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rightTexture")
    } else if v.dx < -abs(v.dy) {
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "leftTexture")
    } else if v.dy < 0 {
        yourPlayer.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "frontTexture")
    } else if v.dy > 0 {
        yourPlayer.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "backTexture")
    }
    //This code moves your character where-ever you want it too
    let xScale = CGFloat(4) //adjust to your preference. Higher means slower, lower means faster
    let yScale = CGFloat(4) //adjust to your preference. Higher means slower, lower means faster

    let xAdd = xScale * self.xJoystickDelta
    let yAdd = yScale * self.yJoystickDelta

    yourPlayerNode.position.x += xAdd
    yourPlayerNode.position.y += yAdd
```

These things need to be outside your `didMove(toView:)` method:

```
var xJoystickDelta:CGFloat = 0
var yJoystickDelta:CGFloat = 0
var v = CGVector()
var isTracking:Bool = false

var DPad = SKSpriteNode()
var thumbNode = SKSpriteNode()
```

**-Explanation-**

In the `touchesBegan` method, the if-statement is testing to see if you are not controlling the thumbNode and if your touch is inside the DPad Node. Then it starts the tracking.

In the `touchesMoved` once `isTracking == true` it starts calculating the neccessary math and then adjusting the various things required. (its complicated, what matters most is that it works.)

In the `touchesEnded` method, it is testing to see when you lift your finger off of the screen, then it resets everything for the next usage.

In the `update(_ current:)` method, the code is calculating the angle of the `CGVector` and then setting a texture (or whatever you want to do) inside of the various cases. Then its calculating the position of the thumbNode inside the DPad and moving your player (or whatever you need to move) around in the scene. Adjust the `xScale` and `yScale` floats higher to slow down the movement, and lower to increase the movement of whatever you are trying to move.

**-Extra neccessary stuff-**

You need to set up the `DPad` and `thumbNode` inside your `didMove(toView:)` method:

```
thumbNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
DPad.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
DPad.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
thumbNode.position = DPad.position
DPad.zPosition = 3
thumbNode.zPosition = 4
DPad.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "yourBaseTexture")
thumbNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "yourStickTexture")

self.addChild(thumbNode)
self.addChild(DPad)
```

You only have to move the `DPad.position` to wherever you want. The thumbNode will move along with it. Also, if you have any problems be sure to ask me so I can help you.